# raise error if files output some error (without raising shell error)

Tags: shell, error-handling

I want to do raise an error if an executable outputs something specific...(like "error"):

`echo "abcdef" | [[ "$(grep "f")" != "" ]] && echo "error"`

> "error"

`echo "abcdef" | [[ "$(grep "g")" != "" ]] && echo "error"`

> ""

This work but when applying it to an exe it fails

```
test_if_exe_fails(){
    $1 | [[ "$(grep "$2")" != "" ]] && echo "error: $2" && exit 1
}
```

when running `myApp.exe | test_if_exe_fails "myerror message"` it exits

> line xxx: myerror : command not found

so I tried using [this method](https://superuser.com/questions/461946/can-i-use-pipe-output-as-a-shell-script-argument/938428) but still doesn't work

let's say the output of my exe start with "BLA BLA FOO", if I do:

`test_if_exe_fails "$(myApp.exe)" "myerror message"`

it gives :

> line xxx: BLA : command not found

---

more examples:

1/ 
`test_if_exe_fails "$(echo 'hello')" "hola"`

> line xx: hello: command not found

2/
`test_if_exe_fails "$(echo 'hello')" "hello"`

> line xx: hello: command not found

Comment: 2 issues: (1) Your function takes 2 arguments and tries to run the first argument. When you tried to test it you did the same thing - ran it yourself, not passed the name in to run (2) the way you have implemented does not allow the function to have arguments, so the way you tested it is what you should implement.

Comment: I am pipelining

Comment: and I want to do a function

Comment: Ok, after your edit, what do you mean by $(myApp.exe) ?  That is still running the program and passing the output in, but your function is expecting to run the program.

Comment: If you really want that behaviour, you could simply `<<<$1`

Comment: I want to run my app, and if during its execution, it outputs some "message" I want to do something

Comment: could you add more detail? like an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `[[ ... ]]` is to generate an exit code that `if`, `&&`, or `||` can test. `grep` already does that. You don't care about `grep`'s output, and you can suppress it with the `-q` option.

```
echo "abcdef" | grep -q "f" && echo "error"
```

Note that your function is wrapping the pipeline, but you have removed the `echo` command. You need to put that back. (Actually, you should use `printf` instead of `echo` for portability and predictability. And finally, error messages should be written to standard error, not standard output.

```
test_if_exe_fails(){
    print '%s' "$1" |  grep -q "$2" && echo "error: $2" >&2 && exit 1
}

test_if_exe_fails "$(myApp.exe)" "myerror message"
```

One last improvement: rather than capture the output of `myApp.exe`, just pipe it directly to the function:

```
test_if_exe_fails(){
    grep -q "$1" && echo "error: $1" >&2 && exit 1
}

myApp.exe | test_if_exe_fails "myerror message"
```

Answer (score -2):

So your function

```
test_if_exe_fails(){
$1 | [[ "$(grep "$2")" != "" ]] && echo "error: $2" && exit 1
}
```

Says "Run the program $1 and grep the output for $2"

That means that when you call this function you should supply the NAME of the program you want to run.

But that is silly. In the examples with echo you want arguments, so you can't do that like that. There are a number of ways to solve this, but they all involve the function NOT RUNNING THE PROGRAM AGAIN!

Comment: where is you solution? this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: "There are a number of ways to solve this" .... I just need one

Comment: Well what do you want to do pipe it in or put the value in as an argument? You asked for morew detail. I can't put more detail in a comment.